# jq add large value to existing json

Tags: json, jq

I have a large existing json object and I'd like to add a new key/value to the object where the value can be very large (many K).

Using jq I can do something like this:

`echo $item | jq '. + {readme:"big blob of text"}'`

Is there a good way to replace `big blob of text` with a shell or jq variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is illustrative of what can be done if your version of jq supports "--argjson".  Similar things can be done with `--arg` and `--argfile`.

```
#!/bin/bash

function bigblob {
cat <<EOF 
big blob of text
EOF
}

item='{"a": "a"}'

bigblob | jq -R --argjson item "$item" '$item + {"readme": .}'
```

Result:

```
{
  "a": "a",
  "readme": "big blob of text"
}
```